# Python 3.9: For loop is not producing output files eventhough no errors are displayed

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, split

everyone, I am fairly new to using python for data analysis,so apologies for silly questions:

*IDE : PyCharm*

**What I have :** A massive .xyz file (with 4 columns) which is a combination of several datasets, each dataset can be determined by the third column of the file which goes from 10,000 to -10,000 with 0 in between and 100 as spacing and repeats (so every 201 rows is one dataset)

**What I want to do :** Split the massive file into its individual datasets (201 rows each)and save each file under a different name.

**What I have done so far :**

```
# Import packages

import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np #For next steps
import math #For next steps

#Check and Change directory

path = 'C:/Clayton/lines/profiles_aufmod'
os.chdir(path)
print(os.getcwd()) #Correct path is printed

# split the xyz file into different files for each profile

main_xyz = 'bathy_SPO_1984_50x50_profile.xyz'

number_lines = sum(1 for row in (open(main_xyz)))
print(number_lines) # 10854 is the output
rowsize = 201

for i in range(number_lines, rowsize):
    profile_raw_df = pd.read_csv(main_xyz, delimiter=',', header=None, nrows=rowsize,
                                 skiprows=i)
    out_xyz = 'Profile' + str(i) + '.xyz'
    profile_raw_df.to_csv(out_xyz, index=False,
                          header=False, mode='a')
```

**Problems I am facing :**

- The for loop was at first giving output files as seen in the image,check [Proof of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gXHX.jpg) but now it does not produce any outputs and it is not rewriting the previous files either. The other mystery is that I am not getting an error either,check [Code executed without error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzoqR.png).

**What I tried to fix the issue :**

- I updated all the packages and restarted Pycharm
- I ran each line of code one by one and everything works until the **for loop**

Comment: If your file has more than 200 lines, the range will obviously be empty.

Comment: Hello Jörg, thank you for your time, My file does have more than 200 lines (10854 to be precise) but as I mentioned before, the above code did run and give me the output files before, it is just not working again. Sorry again for any silly oversight here.

Comment: The range from 10854 to 201 is empty, therefore the loop never executes, since there is nothing to iterate over.

Comment: I understand, is there a better way to write the for loop for the above mentioned purpose? Thank you again for your time

Comment: I don't understand what the purpose of iterating over a range from the number of lines to the rowsize is in the first place. It makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While counting the number of rows in

```
number_lines = sum(1 for row in (open(main_xyz)))
```

you have exhausted the iterator that loops over the lines of the file. But you do not close the file. But this should not prevent Pandas from reading the same file.

A better idiom would be

```
with open(main_xyz) as fh:
  number_lines = sum(1 for row in fh)
```

Your for loop as it stands does not do what you probably want. I guess you want:

```
for i in range(0, number_lines, rowsize):
```

so, `rowsize` is the step-size, instead of the end value of the for loop.

If you want to number the output files by data set, keep a counnt of the dataset, like this

```py
data_set = 0
for i in range(0, number_lines, rowsize):
    data_set += 1
    ...
    out_xyz = f"Profile{data_set}.xyz"
    ...
```

Comment: Dear Dirk, Thank you so much for the help, it really worked well and as required. I just had a tangential question, my new files as you expect are named as profile0, profile201,profile402... based on the 'i' . I was hoping to get them named as profile0, profile1,profile2.....profile54, would it require a nested for loop? Thanks in advance

Comment: no nested for-loop needed, see my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks once again, solved all my problems! thank you for your time!